# Bootstrap 3 breakpoints not working w/ Rain/Tpl

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, raintpl

I'm trying to display the Instagram feed on a website, but the column breakpoint is not working.

When in a small device all the columns on the other sections stacks like they are supposed to, but for this part the feed part it is no stacking. They still side by side even in a small screen device.

I didn't do any customization for the bootstrap.
The custom css for the images is listed below.

I'm suspecting that my css is interfering with it somehow, but i didn't find a solution. Can you help me?

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="instagram-feed">
      {loop="$feed"}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 instagram-image">
            <a
            href="{$value.permalink}"
            target="_blank"
            style="background-image: url('{$value.media_url}')"
            ></a>
        </div>
      {/loop}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 gallery-link" >
            <p>
                xpto
                <a
                  href="https://www.instagram.com/xpto/"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >instagram</a
                >
              </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i'm using rain/tpl to loop the values.

Rendered result:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 instagram-image">
  <a
    href="https://www.instagram.com/p/Ce3K0vtqwWg/"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener"
    style="
      background-image: url('https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/288042510_360927436108874_1443195410220397807_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&amp;ccb=1-7&amp;_nc_sid=8ae9d6&amp;_nc_ohc=BcBzX46rui8AX9LhNfW&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;edm=ANQ71j8EAAAA&amp;oh=00_AT-UQWOTJQXMvRivbpb7IAutNaT6D2_1ws1WdzhSNMARWA&amp;oe=62B4FE5D');"
  >
  </a>
</div>
```

The css i added for this part:

```css
.instagram-image a:before {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: var(--primary);
  background-color: #73a2a9;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.instagram-image a:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#instagram-feed {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What's the rendered output? Are you loading the library correctly?

Comment: The breakpoint for the columns isn't working on this section. It works for all other sections of the page. when i open it in a mobile all sections stacks like it is supposed to, but these pictures stay side by side.

Comment: Please update your question with that information. It doesn't belong down here. See [ask].